# Leaflet with extern Button

Tags: button, leaflet, extern

My leaflet card works fine with the following code. If you click on a marker, a popup with the address also opens. Now I would like to create a button externally for each station that creates the marker and at the same time shows the popup with the address on the map. The data could be delivered through the button. Does it work like this, btw. does anyone have an idea how to change the code and how to write the function (?) in the button?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Leaflet Map</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
    integrity="sha402-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2aocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19sSR7A=="
    crossorigin=""/>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
integrity="sha402-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrUearIOnxwA=="
crossorigin=""></script>

<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 540px"></div>

<script>
var planes = [
["<b>Aral tkst</b><br>Fribert-Str. 14",40.6027069,7.185095],
["<b>Esso tkst</b><br>Alee 63",40.603758,7.16498],
["<b>Shell tkst</b><br>Hener Str. 100",40.609695,7.181562],
["<b>Jet tkst</b><br>Kullee 5",40.6057,2.90240],
["<b>Total tkst</b><br>Caper Str. 123",40.604639,2.914727],
["<b>Shell tkst</b><br>Blistr. 97",40.593768,2.920507],
["<b>Bavaria tkst</b><br>Bumer Str. 1",40.5827866,2.913093],
["<b>Markant tkst</b><br>Her Str.  249",40.58409,2.91258],
];
var map = L.map('map').setView([40.58903, 7.17594], 13)

var circle = L.circle([40.58903, 7.17594], {
color: 'red',
fillColor: '#f03',
fillOpacity: 0.5,
radius: 150
}).addTo(map);

circle.bindPopup("<b>Eigene Adresse:</b><br>Weg 1");

mapLink = 
'<a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>';
L.tileLayer(
'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
attribution: '&copy; ' + mapLink + ' bvchim',
maxZoom: 18,
}).addTo(map);

for (var i = 0; i < planes.length; i++) {
marker = new L.marker([planes[i][1],planes[i][2]])
.bindPopup(planes[i][0])
.addTo(map);
}
               
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
var container = document.getElementById('button-container');
for (var i = 0; i < planes.length; i++) {
  var marker = new L.marker([planes[i][1],planes[i][2]])
    .bindPopup(planes[i][0])
    .addTo(map);
     
   var btn = document.createElement('button');
   btn.id = L.stamp(marker); // set the id of the marker as button id
   btn.innerHTML = planes[i][0];
   
   L.DomEvent.on(btn,'click',(e)=>{
    var target = e.target;
    if(target.nodeName !== "BUTTON"){ // Needed because the target can also be the <b> Element
        target = target.parentNode;
    }
    var btn2 = target
    var marker2 = map._layers[btn2.id]; // get marker over id
    var latlng = marker2.getLatLng();
    map.panTo(latlng);
    marker2.openPopup();    
   })
   container.appendChild(btn);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/my0o5Lav/

Comment: @scotty030253 if this works for you, please accept the answer as correct

Comment: Is it possible to place the buttons in 2 rows 4 buttons each to the right of the map?

Comment: yes this is possible with default css and html. Set the `button-container` to the right of the map with css and then fill it with the buttons. Also you can add after the 4 btn a break aith `<br>` then the next buttons are in a new line

Comment: Can you change your first example so that 4 buttons appear one below the other and 2 buttons next to each other to the right of the map? My knowledge is still a bit modest.

Comment: I updated the jsfiddle. If you have more questions please create a new question on SO

Comment: Thank you so much! I can really still learn a lot here.